# AWSSDK not generating new PreSigned URLs (always expired)

Tags: c#, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

I have a private bucket that generates pre-signed URLs that expires in 300 seconds (5 minutes), in total there are 10 images stored, but 1 image always generates an expired URL (it never updates the expire time). I have tried with different browsers and devices in different computers, it isn't a caché or temp problem.

I'm using AWSSDK 1.5.2.2, my code to generate the URLs is the next:

```
public string GetPreSignedURL(string bucketName, string keyName, System.DateTime expiration)
{
    GetPreSignedUrlRequest urlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest();
    urlRequest.BucketName = bucketName;
    urlRequest.Key = keyName;
    urlRequest.Expires = expiration;
    urlRequest.Protocol = this.AwsProtocol;
    return this.S3.GetPreSignedURL(urlRequest);
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
this.image = this.AWSManager.GetPreSignedURL(bucketName, keyName, this.GetExpireTime());
```

The GetExpireTime() method is this:

```
private DateTime GetExpireTime()
{
    int expireTime;
    try
    {
        expireTime = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["expireTime"].ToString());
    }
    catch
    {
        expireTime = defaultExpireTime;
    }
    return DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(expireTime);
}
```

Of the 10 images that are stored in AWS, there is always one, and the same image that returns the same URL everytime it is generated (only happens in production, so I have no way to debug). I connected the develop environment to the production bucket, and replicated the DB register to see if I can replicate the problem, but in my local machine the URL gets generated just fine.

Here is a URL that was generated at 9:34 AM:

```
https://gtidev-masorden.s3.amazonaws.com/P4285735_thumbnail.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJTCJB4KPHVI4HTXQ&Expires=1550177695&Signature=f0Llq2syEvDvgdhxYHeedHCpD8s%3D
```

And here is one generated at 10:00 AM:

```
https://gtidev-masorden.s3.amazonaws.com/P4285735_thumbnail.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJTCJB4KPHVI4HTXQ&Expires=1550177695&Signature=f0Llq2syEvDvgdhxYHeedHCpD8s%3D
```

I compare every generated URL here:

```
https://text-compare.com/
```

And it's always the same URL, no changes in Expires param or Signature param. When I reupload the picture, it starts to generate valid urls again but a few minutes later, another picture starts to fail.

EDIT:I have been requesting the same image for about 4 days and the expiration date is the same. When I open the URL in a new tab,  this is what it says:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Request has expired</Message>
<Expires>2019-02-14T20:54:55Z</Expires>
<ServerTime>2019-02-18T17:09:27Z</ServerTime>
<RequestId>C78E43335EE8E845</RequestId>
<HostId>
PPHXhK6Oj7PEKOqb8io1IcVY6mfqNM5zc89ttLylzH/DKPldIo0v8pukdW4SZmqACAVn8WSyIu0=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Perhaps I'm missing somethig, and I don't want to update the AWSSDK because others projects depend on it. Any ideas?

Comment: I would check the Event Logs to see if there is an error at time of transfer.  I suspect either the credentials of the file are wrong or the file is corrupt (try opening the file to make sure it valid).

Comment: The file is valid, because it was working a week ago and I can see it on CloudBerry. Also, if it were the credentials other images should fail too, right?

Comment: I've seen plenty of cases where a file gets corrupted.  I also have seen lots of case where an admin looks at a file and then saves it so nobody else can read the file.

Comment: How can I test this? Because I can see the file in the Amazon Console, I just edited the question to add what the URLs says when I request it.

Comment: It is taking 4 days for the time to expire. Why?  I have a suspicion that you are using UTF time and and then comparing against local time.

Comment: No, I explained myself wrong, I have been refreshing the site every hour for 4 days to see if the URL changes, but always returns the same, I pasted the code I use to generate the expire time, it is 300 seconds.

Comment: Check the datetime in the bin /debug and bin/release folder and see if the release folder executable was updated.